# How do I bypass protect_from_forgery in Rails 3 for a Facebook canvas app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, csrf

I have a Rails 3 Facebook canvas app. When it loads up it gives me an invalid authenticity token error and displays the `signed_request` parameter that Facebook sends to my app. Is there a way to bypass the 'protect_from_forgery' for the signed_request from facebook?

Thanks!

Tim

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Problem solved. I added

`skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [THE ACTION]`

to the top of my controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just remove protect_from_forgery from the application controller, if you only use the app as a canvas app.