# Writing to Rails with a JSON API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

I've been trying to write to a regular one model rails app from [POSTman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) for a few days now, and can't figure out how to do it, or find any information on how to do it.

My app has a User model with a name field. All I'm trying to do is change the name remotely via JSON using POSTman.

Any help on how to do this is appreciated, including a link to a basic resource on how to do it.

I imagine this is pretty basic.

EDIT: here is a screenshot from the POSTman output

[image]

EDIT 2:

from server log:

```
Started PUT "/users/1.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-17 16:53:36 -0400
Processing by UsersController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"name"=>"Jeff", "id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
Completed 204 No Content in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

The transaction is happening, but the record isn't actually being updated. Do I need to change something in the controller? It's just a regular rails generated controller with no changes.

EDIT 3:

Here is my output from just going to `http://localhost:3000/users/1.json`

```
{
"created_at": "2013-07-02T21:51:22Z",
"id": 1,
"name": "Arel",
"updated_at": "2013-07-02T21:51:22Z"
}
```

Again, I've changed nothing from the scaffold, and I haven't been able to figure out how to format the JSON to nest it under user like the answer suggests.

Here is the relevant part of my controller:

```
# GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

# PUT /users/1
  # PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json {  }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I don't understand why this is so difficult. I'm just trying to update a name via JSON ...

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you seeing any output in the rails server log?

Comment: It just does nothing. When I put the address http://localhost:3000/users/1.json and select PUT with the key as name and the value as Jeff 204 no content is returned

Comment: @diego.greyrobot I just added a screenshot of what I've been trying to do.

Comment: You are probably seeing this in your logs, right? "WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity"

Comment: Yes! How can I disable this for just the JSON request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the controller you want to post to:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

or like from: [How do I bypass protect_from_forgery in Rails 3 for a Facebook canvas app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551210/how-do-i-bypass-protect-from-forgery-in-rails-3-for-a-facebook-canvas-app)

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [THE ACTION]
```

EDIT

Your JSON is incorrect... you are posting

```
{"name"=>"Jeff", "id"=>"1"}
```

Since your controller does `user.update_attribute(params[:user])`, your JSON needs to be under a user attribute

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "user": {
        "name": "Jeff"
    }
}
```

This will create a hash of

```
{"user"=>{"name"=>"Jeff"}, "id"=>"1"}
```

Comment: So now it's not giving a CSRF token error, but still is giving a 204 no content error after committing the transaction. I've updated my question with the full output.

Comment: I'm totally lost here. I've been reading the rails docs trying to figure out how to format my JSON output the way you show, and they say that the output should already be your way, and only give instructions on how to change away from your(correct) format to my incorrect format. Here are the docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html I've also updated my question with my output, and my controller.

Comment: Output is irrelevant. You are sending in input. The input format is different that the output format. In postman, change the name of your field to "user[name]"